# Failed to install ffmpeg. Failed to download resource "x265"

Tags: ffmpeg, homebrew, failed-installation

I was trying to run "brew install ffmpeg" and two download links failed. So it failed the installation.

Those are the links that aren't working:

```
==> Downloading https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/git-htmldocs-2.28.0.tar.
==> Downloading https://bitbucket.org/multicoreware/x265/downloads/x265_3.4.tar.gz
```

I got this errors:

```
Error: Failed to download resource "git--html"

Download failed: https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/git-htmldocs-2.28.0.tar.xz

Error: Failed to download resource "x265"

Download failed: https://bitbucket.org/multicoreware/x265/downloads/x265_3.4.tar.gz
```

Comment: If you go to the bitbucket link you'll see "Bitbucket no longer supports Mercurial repositories". Might need to log an issue: https://github.com/homebrew-ffmpeg/homebrew-ffmpeg

Comment: There is a git repo that can be used instead: `git clone https://bitbucket.org/multicoreware/x265_git.git x265`

Comment: Thank you! I ended up installing directly from the binary file on https://evermeet.cx/ffmpeg/ but next time I'll try this one